# Scalaz finding for a certain type in a NonEmptyList[MyType]

Tags: scala, scalaz

I have a validated type which I pass to a function and in that function, I pattern match for Success and Failure and in the Failure block, I would like to see from the NonEmptyList if there is a certain type and if yes, I would like to return true else false.

I sort of wrote it, but I feel it could be simplified.

```
def checkTypeVaialble(param: V[Param]): Boolean = param match {
  case Success(succ) => false
  case Failure(fail) => {
    val bools = fail.map {
      case MyTypeA => true
      case _       => false
    }
    val filtered = bools.list.filter(x => x == true)
    if(!filtered.isEmpty) true else false
  }
}
```

Is there a much simpler way? What I do is to map all the failures into a List of Booleans and I filter the List of Booleans for true and return the result of isEmpty. Can I simplify it furthermore?

Comment: I'm not asking to check for a certain type as I already do that. I just want to simplify my case Failure in my code snippet above

Comment: Matching on type is at odds with the purely-functional approach preferred by Scalaz (and is fairly broken in Scala, anyway).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using collect or collectFirst should work:

```
def checkTypeVaialble(param: V[Param]): Boolean = param match {
  case Success(succ) => false
  case Failure(fail) => fail.collectFirst{ case m:MyTypeA => true}.isDefined;  
}
```

Alternatively, you can use exists with pattern match:

```
def checkTypeVaialble(param: V[Param]): Boolean = param match {
  case Success(succ) => false
  case Failure(fail) => fail.exists{ case m:MyTypeA => true; case _ => false};  
}
```

Note that `collect`, already ignores the case where the match fails. For `exists`, however, you need to provide the match all cases or you get a MatchError